# Can't get username from req.user to output in express

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm using ejs to try to output a username from req.user in a node express app, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is where my username and password come in:

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
        user: req.user
    }); 
    console.log("req.user:", req.user);
});
```

At this point, I can see req.user in terminal displayed like this:

```js
req.user: [ { _id: 5890f8a97ef995525d4b78cd,
    username: 'dave',
    password: 'somepassword',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

This is what I have in index.ejs:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<head>
<body>
  <% if (!isAuthenticated) { %>
    <a href="/login">Log in here</a>
  <% } else { %>
    Hello, <%= user.username %>!
    <a href="/logout">Log out</a>
  <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the login form:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Passport</title>
<head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I initially had this in my index.ejs, but still did not output username.

```js
Hello, <%= user.name %>!
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what your terminal displayed, it looks like `req.user` is an array containing objects, which means that you would need to access one of the elements in the array before accessing the object's properties.

Therefore `<%= user.username %>` would be `<%= user[0].username %>`:

```
<% if (!isAuthenticated) { %>
  <a href="/login">Log in here</a>
<% } else { %>
  Hello, <%= user[0].username %>!
  <a href="/logout">Log out</a>
<% } %>
```

Or you could just update the web service to pass in the first element in the `user` array:

```
res.render('index', {
  isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
  user: req.user[0]
});
```

```
<% if (!isAuthenticated) { %>
  <a href="/login">Log in here</a>
<% } else { %>
  Hello, <%= user.username %>!
  <a href="/logout">Log out</a>
<% } %>
```

You may also want to check if the `user` array contains any elements to prevent any errors from being thrown if it doesn't:

```
res.render('index', {
  isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
  user: (req.user && req.user.length) ? req.user[0] : {}
});
```

Comment: Josh, thanks for your suggestions.  Unfortunately, the 2 changes I tried did not work.  Updating the index.ejs page with `Hello, <%= user[0].username %>!` resulted in this error:
`GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`
The second solution also rendered an error of: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.`

Comment: Josh, I got this working. Part of your first solution was correct, I will give you credit and just update the answer here.   I just changed it to `username[0].username` and used `username: req.user` instead of `user:req.user` In .  The key in `username` should match how the property in the object is used.